# Registry GetValue function

Tags: c#, .net, registry

I am trying to get values and set values to the Registry .

When I am trying to access a path that not located at the registry I am getting exception.

But when I am setting that path with `Registry.SetValue(keyName, "", 0);`, all works fine and I can get  non existing values from it.

Any idea why I can't use my `public int GetComponent(string RegKey)` function on nun existing paths?

```
public class LP_Registery
{
    private const string userRoot = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER";
    private const string subkey   = @"Software\PCBMatrix\LPWizard";
    private string keyName;

    public LP_Registery(string folderName) => keyName = userRoot + "\\" +  subkey + "\\" + folderName;
    public int GetComponent(string RegKey) => (int)Registry.GetValue(keyName, RegKey, 0); 
    public void SetComponent(string RegKey, int RegVal) => Registry.SetValue(keyName, RegKey, RegVal, RegistryValueKind.DWord);
}
```

And if it possible what should i do that it will be possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

surround the GetValue with *try - catch* block and enjoy the coding.

Exceptions and Conditions of **GetValue**:

> *SecurityException*:
>   The user does not have the permissions required to read from the registry key.
>
> *IOException*:     The RegistryKey that
>   contains the specified value has been
>   marked for deletion.
>
> *ArgumentException*: keyName does not
>   begin with a valid registry root.

---

**SetValue** method:

> Sets the specified name/value pair on
>   the specified registry key. ***If the
>   specified key does not exist, it is
>   created.***